# Why logcat returns nothing when I adb logcal my.app.package.name?

Tags: console, android-logcat

I am trying to use the terminal to attach to device's `logcat` to get output for my app. The syntax I am using is this

```
adb -d logcat my.app.package.name *:S
```

but when I type this command, I get empty output like

```
$ adb -d logcat my.app.package.name *:S
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
```

However, if I monitor messages globally on the device via `adb -d logcat *:E`, then I can see error generated by my application.

Why am I not getting anything with the upper command? The semantics is OK as per Google docs (http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html). Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Note: If I try with GREP like `adb -d logcat | grep "my app"`, then I do get logcat logs.